# Is a probability measure uqual to the product of the marginal measures?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $P$ a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Is it true that $P(\prod_{k=1}^d(A_k))=\prod_{k=1}^d (P\circ\pi^{-1}_k(A_k))$ where $\pi_k:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the kth projection?

This fact is trivially false if the measure is not a probability measure (for example take the Lebesgue measure). Can someone help me to prove the statement or to find a counterexample?

Moreover, why $P$ is tight if and only if $(P\circ\pi^{-1}_k)$ are tight for all k?

Comment: That equality actually holding is "independence" of the components. There are plenty of ways for that to fail. Also, that product doesn't actually make proper sense; the domain is wrong. You want a "tensor product" which applies $\pi_k^{-1}$ to the $k$th component.

Comment: I tried to fix my definition and I added a question

Answer (score 0):

Try the joint distribution of any $d$ random variables that are not independent.